# Issues with component lifecycles / cannot handle undefined

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, fetch

I am making an app which is supposed to at certain point fetch a feed of information with title, description and user info. I am doing this in react native, these is also two separate feeds within the same view, which can switch between two tabs, so I thought that my current architechture would subsequently be optimal.

The problem at hand:

From Methods.js:

```
exports.getFriendFeed = function(TOKEN) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(baseUrl + 'feed' , {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Token' : TOKEN,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((responseText) => {

        resolve(responseText);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
    });
  });
};
```

I write the fetch request and send it to my home.js screen. And process it as follows:

```
var Home = React.createClass({
.
.
.
  changeComponent: function(component) {
    Method.getFriendFeed(this.state.tokenSupreme)
    .then((res) => this.setState({
      friendFeed: JSON.parse(res).friendPosts,
      loaded: true,
    }))
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .done();     
    this.setState({
      componentSelected: component,
    })
  },
```

Meaning that when I press into a certain feed-view the content specifically loads for that view.

Rendering the component and passing the props of the information feed and whether or not it is loaded:

```
  renderComponent: function(component) {
      if(component === 'One') {
        return <ComponentOne 
        friendData={
          this.state.friendFeed
        } 
        loaded={
          this.state.loaded
        } />
      } else if(component === 'Two') {
        return <ComponentTwo />
      }
  },
```

But now comes the real issue. Following the documentation provided by React Native. I have `console.log`'ed the rowData yielding "loading" and then it returns the json format data that I want. So this means that it passes through the `changeComponent` function successfully at first and becomes "loading", and mistakingly turns `this.state.loaded` to be `true`, this means however that there is a point in time during this execution where I cannot call any specific keyes or names in my json due to the fact that it has only "kind of" loaded, which just returns undefined and red screens the app immediately.

```
var ComponentOne = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
     return { 
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this.props.friendData),
   };
  },

  render: function() {
    if (!this.props.loaded) {
      return this.renderLoadingView(); 
    } else {
    return (
       <ListView 
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource} 
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          style={styles.card} /> 
      )
    }
  },
   renderLoadingView: function() { 
    return ( 
      <View style={{alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 150, justifyContent: 'center'}} > 
        <Text style={{fontSize: 30, fontWeight: '400', color: '#666'}}> Loading ... </Text> 
      </View> 
      ); 
  },  

  renderRow: function(rowData) {
    return (
        <CardView
          name={rowData.name}
          fullname='xyz'
          distance='xyz'
          title={rowData.title}
          message={rowData.description} 
          score='xyz'
          stars='xyz'
          starcolors={colors.General.black}
          vouched="Example" />
      )
  }
})
```

Why does it give me this?? It never really fires of if I put the fetcher in a componentDidMount and if I put it in a render, it fires ad infinitum.

How can I more efficiently control this execution/life-cycle issue?? I also tried to make it an IF statement saying `if (this.props.friendFeed.friend.name !== undefined)` but believe it or not, it just returns a red screen saying `this.props.friendFeed.friend.name is undefined`. Could it be an issue calling an object within a Key? Could I call such a thing without it being undefined before it is defined?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions. First, regarding your last question about calling a key on an undefined object. Consider this object...

```
{
  foo: {
    bar: 'text'
  }
}
```

If at any point `foo` is `undefined`, you cannot check if a sub object key is also `undefined`. You need to determine the highest root object that could be undefined when the data is loading.

So, this statement would fail: `if (foo.bar !== undefined)` if `foo` is `undefined`. However, this statement would be ok: `if (foo.hasOwnProperty('bar'))` or technically even `if (foo !== undefined)`.

As for your main issue, my guess is there's something async happening to the data parsing. This is how I implement `fetch`...

```
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response.text().then((text) => {
      if (text == "") return ""
      return JSON.parse(text)
    })
    return response.json()
  }
}

get(id, query) {
  let url = this.API_URL() + '/' + id + this._generateQuery(query)
  return fetch(url, {
    method: 'get',
    headers: this._headers()
  }).then(this._checkStatus)
    .then((data) => {
      return data
    })
```

}

Notice how I have to tap into the promise side of processing the body into text. I would try doing something like that in your `changeComponent` so that it doesn't call `setState` (and subsequently setting loading to true) until you're sure the data is parsed. Since it's inline, it might be calling `setState` immediately and then for a brief moment render the component with incomplete data while it finishes the parse (since it's just passing around the variable references, not values).